# Rotate arrowheads in tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-3dplot

This question is similar to this one I asked before: [How to apply 3D transform to arrows in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432170/how-to-apply-3d-transform-to-arrows-in-tikz).

But there I was using the `3d` library in TikZ. This question is about `tikz-3dplot`.

How can I rotate the arrowheads? Consider this minimal example:

[image]

Take the z-axis arrowhead as an example. I would like to be able to transform it so it lies in x-z plane or y-z plane. Is this possible?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267497/51022

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `3d` library to be able to use `canvas is xz plane at y` and `\pgflowlevelsynccm` to transform the arrows. The following has the `z` axis in the xz plane and the two other axes in the xy plane.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
 \path  (0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$}; 
 \pgflowlevelsynccm
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,1); 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
 \path (1,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$}
  (0,1)  node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
 \pgflowlevelsynccm
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]