Given a normal vector, is it possible to re-orient tikz arrows and node letters so that they are level with an arbitrary plane?
Note: I realize that this question is asking a lot, I just really want this functionality. Sorry for such a long and involved question.
Also, a normal vector to the plane in my diagram is (1.5,-2,1).

Given a normal vector, is it possible to re-orient tikz arrows and node letters so that they are level with an arbitrary plane?
Similar to how the arrow is drawn in perspective in this example from page 84 of the asymptote manual:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267497/319072 is above my level, though it does seem to implement this feature, given angles. I want to do something similar, using a normal vector. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531156/319072 only seems to implement is for the xy, yz and xz planes.
Here is a non-MWE (the reason for it being so long is to help you visualize the problem)
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\newcommand{\planeFunction}[2]{
% Purpose: defines a plane.
% #1  - x variable
% #2  - y variable
% Return: the output in z.
-1.5*(#1)+2*(#2)+2
}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies}]

% plane
\foreach \Vt in {-2,-1.9,...,1}{
\draw[very thin,densely dotted] (\Vt,-2,{\planeFunction{\Vt}{-2}}) -- (\Vt,1,{\planeFunction{\Vt}{1}});
\draw[very thin,densely dotted] (-2,\Vt,{\planeFunction{-2}{\Vt}}) -- (1,\Vt,{\planeFunction{1}{\Vt}});
}

% xy grid
\foreach \Vt in {-2.8,-2.6,...,2.8}{
\draw[very thin,densely dotted] (\Vt,-3) -- (\Vt,3);
\draw[very thin,densely dotted] (-3,\Vt) -- (3,\Vt);
}

% xy axes
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[pos=1,below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[pos=1,above right] {$y$};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% arrow on xy grid - how do I make it level with the plane? %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\spy on (2.8,0) in node at (6,-2);

% shadow of domain on the xy plane
\fill[opacity=0.3] (-2,-2) -- (-2,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,-2) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}
\clip (-4/3,-2) -- (1,-0.25) -- (1,1,{\planeFunction{1}{1}}) -- (-2,1,{\planeFunction{-2}{1}}) -- (-2,-2,{\planeFunction{-2}{-2}}) -- cycle;
\fill[white] (-4/3,-2) -- (1,-0.25) -- (1,1,{\planeFunction{1}{1}}) -- (-2,1,{\planeFunction{-2}{1}}) -- (-2,-2,{\planeFunction{-2}{-2}}) -- cycle;

% plane
\foreach \Vt in {-2,-1.9,...,1}{
\draw[very thin,densely dotted] (\Vt,-2,{\planeFunction{\Vt}{-2}}) -- (\Vt,1,{\planeFunction{\Vt}{1}});
\draw[very thin,densely dotted] (-2,\Vt,{\planeFunction{-2}{\Vt}}) -- (1,\Vt,{\planeFunction{1}{\Vt}});
}
\end{scope}

% intersection line
\draw (1,-0.25) -- (-4/3,-2);

% shadow of plane
\fill[opacity=0.3] (1,-2,{\planeFunction{1}{-2}}) -- (1,1,{\planeFunction{1}{-2}}) -- (1,1,{\planeFunction{1}{1}}) -- cycle;
\fill[opacity=0.3] (1,-2,{\planeFunction{1}{-2}}) -- (-2,-2,{\planeFunction{1}{-2}}) -- (-2,-2,{\planeFunction{-2}{-2}}) -- cycle;


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% arrow on plane - how do I make it level with the plane? %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[->] (0,0,{\planeFunction{0}{0}}) -- (-1,-1,{\planeFunction{-1}{-1}});
\spy on (-1,-1,{\planeFunction{-1}{-1}}) in node at (-4,7);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% letter on plane - how do I make it level with the plane? %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\node at (-1.5,0.5,{\planeFunction{-1.5}{0.5}}) {$\overline{C}$};
\spy on (-1.5,0.5,{\planeFunction{-1.5}{0.5}}) in node at (-6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, font=\tiny]

\draw[teal, ->] (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0);
\draw[teal, ->] (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0);
\draw[teal, ->] (0,0,-3) -- (0,0,3);

%normal vector
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nx}{1.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ny}{-2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nz}{1}

%point in plane
\pgfmathsetmacro{\px}{0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\py}{0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pz}{(-\nx*\px-\ny*\py)/\nz}

%normalize
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nl}{sqrt((\nx)^2+(\ny)^2+(\nz)^2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nx}{\nx/\nl}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ny}{\ny/\nl}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nz}{\nz/\nl}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pl}{sqrt((\px)^2+(\py)^2+(\pz)^2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\px}{\px/\pl}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\py}{\py/\pl}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pz}{\pz/\pl}

%second point in plane
\tdplotcrossprod(\nx,\ny,\nz)(\px,\py,\pz)

\coordinate (X) at (\px,\py,\pz);
\coordinate (Y) at (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz);
\coordinate (Z) at (\nx,\ny,\nz);
\begin{scope}[x={(X)}, y={(Y)}, z={(Z)}, canvas is xy plane at z=0]
\pgflowlevelsynccm
%draw in plane
\draw[step=0.1cm, ultra thin, gray] (0,0) grid (2,2);
\draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[right]{test1};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (2,1) node[right]{test2};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (2,2) node[right]{test3};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (1,2) node[right]{test4};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[right]{test5};
\end{scope}

%show normal and spanning vectors
\draw[->, red] (0,0,0) -- (\nx,\ny,\nz) node[left]{$\hat{\vec n}$};
\draw[->, red] (0,0,0) -- (\px,\py,\pz) node[below right]{$\hat{\vec p_1}$};
\draw[->, red] (0,0,0) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz) node[left]{$\hat{\vec p_2}$};
\draw[densely dotted] (0,\ny,0) -- (\nx,\ny,0) -- (\nx,\ny,\nz) (\nx,0,0) -- (\nx,\ny,0);
\draw[densely dotted] (0,\py,0) -- (\px,\py,0) -- (\px,\py,\pz) (\px,0,0) -- (\px,\py,0);
\draw[densely dotted] (0,\tdplotresy,0) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz) (\tdplotresx,0,0) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{-45}



Appreciate the help! It's always cool to learn some more tikz too.

@Jasper: I have made some changes - I have normalized the vectors, as it seems silly to introduce a arbitrary stretch at the same time.
