Graphing the intersection of 2 planes on Overleaf
I am trying to graph the intersection of the planes 4x-y+3z=4 and 2x-3y+4z=-3 on Overleaf with pgfplots, but I want to include axes and I want both planes to be light grey. I tried copying the code from this old post but there were no axes and the shading didn't work (both planes showed up as bright pink). Also, the line \usetkzobj{all} in the preamble kept showing errors. I don't have code yet because I'm not sure where to start.
Edit: I think I want it to look like something like the first picture but without the textures on the planes and that extra blue line intersecting? Maybe axes are too much of an ask. I just wanted to visually represent that two planes always intersect in a line.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to TeX.SE! I would suggest doing this task in plane TikZ, instead of using software like pgfplots or tkz-euclide. There are multiple ways to achieve this in TikZ, so a lot of decisions are up to stylistic choice. That makes it difficult to give a concrete response - though I can think of two responses which would display good practice.

If you cannot produce a Minimal Working Example- which I would understand given the level of complexity of this task, could you please draw a picture by hand, or find one on the internet that shows what you desire?

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/727935/319072 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727949/319072 for an idea of what I'm getting at for good practice. If you can produce an MWE based on these, I could help you further.

Hi, thank you so much for replying!! I updated the post with example pictures as asked and I’ll try and have a look at the other posts but I really don’t think I can make a MWE at this stage…

I have finally parameterized the solution. The only caveat is that the ordering if the planes is done manually (using spath3). Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730726/319072
To play around with the code, try altering the values of the parameters in the tikzpicture environment.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3,intersections}

\pgfmathsetmacro\elevation{40}
\pgfmathsetmacro\azimuth{120}

\pgfmathsetmacro\xmin{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xmax{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ymin{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ymax{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zmin{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zmax{5}

\pgfmathsetmacro\xmin{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xmax{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ymin{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ymax{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zmin{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zmax{5}

\newcommand{\xP}{}
\newcommand{\yP}{}
\newcommand{\zP}{}

\newcommand{\getPlane}[5]{
\pgfmathsetmacro\aP{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\bP{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cP{#3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dP{#4}
\renewcommand{\xP}[2]{
% #1  - y
% #2  - z
(((\dP)-((\bP)*(##1))-((\cP)*(##2)))/(\aP))
}
\renewcommand{\yP}[2]{
% #1  - x
% #2  - z
(((\dP)-((\aP)*(##1))-((\cP)*(##2)))/(\bP))
}
\renewcommand{\zP}[2]{
% #1  - x
% #2  - y
(((\dP)-((\aP)*(##1))-((\bP)*(##2)))/(\cP))
}

% fill cube
\pgfmathparse{\aP == 0 && \bP == 0 && \cP == 0}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \pgfmathparse{\dP == 0}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \draw[red, fill=green] (\xmin,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmin) -- cycle;
        \draw[red, fill=green] (\xmin,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmax) -- (\xmin,\ymin,\zmax) -- cycle;
        \draw[red, fill=green] (\xmin,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmax) -- (\xmin,\ymin,\zmax) -- cycle;
        \draw[red, fill=green] (\xmin,\ymin,\zmax) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmax) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmax) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmax) -- cycle;
        \draw[red, fill=green] (\xmin,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmax) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmax) -- cycle;
        \draw[red, fill=green] (\xmax,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmax) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmax) -- cycle;
    \else
        % do nothing here
    \fi
\fi

% yz planes
\pgfmathparse{\aP != 0 && \bP == 0 && \cP == 0}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \pgfmathparse{(\xmin <= (\dP/\aP)) && ((\dP/\aP) <= \xmax)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \path[spath/save=#5] ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmin}},\ymin,\zmin) 
        -- ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmin}},\ymax,\zmin) 
        -- ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmax}},\ymax,\zmax) 
        -- ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmax}},\ymin,\zmax) -- cycle;
    \fi
\fi

% xz planes
\pgfmathparse{\aP == 0 && \bP != 0 && \cP == 0}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \pgfmathparse{(\ymin <= (\dP/\bP)) && ((\dP/\bP) <= \ymax)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \path[spath/save=#5] (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmin}},\zmin) 
        -- (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmin}},\zmin) 
        -- (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmax}},\zmax) 
        -- (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmax}},\zmax) -- cycle;
    \fi
\fi

% xy planes
\pgfmathparse{\aP == 0 && \bP == 0 && \cP != 0}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \pgfmathparse{(\zmin <= (\dP/\cP)) && ((\dP/\cP) <= \zmax)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \path[spath/save=#5] (\xmin,\ymin,{\zP{\xmin}{\ymin}}) 
        -- (\xmax,\ymin,{\zP{\xmax}{\ymin}}) 
        -- (\xmax,\ymax,{\zP{\xmax}{\ymax}}) 
        -- (\xmin,\ymax,{\zP{\xmin}{\ymax}}) -- cycle;
    \fi
\fi

% y of x planed (invariant over z)
\pgfmathparse{\aP != 0 && \bP != 0 && \cP == 0}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xylower{\xmin}
    \pgfmathparse{\ymax < \yP{\xmin}{0} || \yP{\xmin}{0} < \ymin}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xylower{\xP{\ymax}{0}}
    \fi

    \pgfmathsetmacro\xyupper{\xmax}
    \pgfmathparse{\ymax < \yP{\xmax}{0} || \yP{\xmax}{0} < \ymin}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xyupper{\xP{\ymin}{0}}
    \fi

    \pgfmathparse{!(\xylower < \xmin || \xylower > \xmax) && !(\xyupper < \xmin || \xyupper > \xmax)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \path[spath/save=#5] 
        (\xylower,{\yP{\xylower}{0}},\zmin) -- 
        (\xyupper,{\yP{\xyupper}{0}},\zmin) -- 
        (\xyupper,{\yP{\xyupper}{0}},\zmax) -- 
        (\xylower,{\yP{\xylower}{0}},\zmax) -- cycle;
    \fi
\fi

% z of x planed (invariant over y)
\pgfmathparse{\aP != 0 && \bP == 0 && \cP != 0}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xzlower{\xmin}
    \pgfmathparse{\zmax < \zP{\xmin}{0} || \zP{\xmin}{0} < \zmin}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xzlower{\xP{0}{\zmax}}
    \fi

    \pgfmathsetmacro\xzupper{\xmax}
    \pgfmathparse{\zmax < \zP{\xmax}{0} || \zP{\xmax}{0} < \zmin}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xzupper{\xP{0}{\zmin}}
    \fi

    \pgfmathparse{!(\xzlower < \xmin || \xzlower > \xmax) && !(\xzupper < \xmin || \xzupper > \xmax)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \path[spath/save=#5] 
        (\xzlower,\ymin,{\zP{\xzlower}{0}}) -- 
        (\xzupper,\ymin,{\zP{\xzupper}{0}}) -- 
        (\xzupper,\ymax,{\zP{\xzupper}{0}}) -- 
        (\xzlower,\ymax,{\zP{\xzlower}{0}}) -- cycle;
    \fi
\fi

% z of y planed (invariant over x)
\pgfmathparse{\aP == 0 && \bP != 0 && \cP != 0}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yzlower{\ymin}
    \pgfmathparse{\zmax < \zP{0}{\ymin} || \zP{0}{\ymin} < \zmin}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\yzlower{\yP{0}{\zmax}}
    \fi

    \pgfmathsetmacro\xzupper{\ymax}
    \pgfmathparse{\zmax < \zP{0}{\ymax} || \zP{0}{\ymax} < \zmin}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\yzupper{\yP{0}{\zmin}}
    \fi

    \pgfmathparse{!(\yzlower < \ymin || \yzlower > \ymax) && !(\yzupper < \ymin || \yzupper > \ymax)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \path[spath/save=#5] 
        (\xmin,\yzlower,{\zP{0}{\yzlower}}) -- 
        (\xmin\yzupper,{\zP{0}{\yzupper}}) -- 
        (\xmax,\yzupper,{\zP{0}{\yzupper}}) -- 
        (\xmax,\yzlower,{\zP{0}{\yzlower}}) -- cycle;
    \fi
\fi

% the final case
\pgfmathparse{\aP != 0 && \bP != 0 && \cP != 0}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1

    \coordinate (xminymin1) at (\xmin,\ymin,{\zP{\xmin}{\ymin}});
    \coordinate (xminymin2) at (\xmin,\ymin,{\zP{\xmin}{\ymin}});
    \pgfmathparse{\zmax < \zP{\xmin}{\ymin}}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \coordinate (xminymin1) at ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmax}},\ymin,{\zP{\xP{\ymin}{\zmax}}{\ymin}});
        \coordinate (xminymin2) at ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmax}},\ymax,{\zP{\xP{\ymax}{\zmax}}{\ymax}});
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymin}{\zmax} > \xmax || \xP{\ymin}{\zmax} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xminymin1) at (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmax}},{\zP{\xmin}{\yP{\xmin}{\zmax}}});
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymax}{\zmax} > \xmax || \xP{\ymax}{\zmax} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xminymin2) at (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmax}},{\zP{\xmin}{\yP{\xmin}{\zmax}}});
        \fi
    \fi
    \pgfmathparse{\zmin > \zP{\xmin}{\ymin}}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \coordinate (xminymin1) at ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmin}},\ymin,{\zP{\xP{\ymin}{\zmin}}{\ymin}});
        \coordinate (xminymin2) at ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmin}},\ymax,{\zP{\xP{\ymax}{\zmin}}{\ymax}});
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymin}{\zmin} > \xmax || \xP{\ymin}{\zmin} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xminymin1) at (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmin}},{\zP{\xmin}{\yP{\xmin}{\zmin}}});
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymax}{\zmin} > \xmax || \xP{\ymax}{\zmin} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xminymin2) at (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmin}},{\zP{\xmin}{\yP{\xmin}{\zmin}}});
        \fi
    \fi

    \coordinate (xmaxymin1) at (\xmax,\ymin,{\zP{\xmax}{\ymin}});
    \coordinate (xmaxymin2) at (\xmax,\ymin,{\zP{\xmax}{\ymin}});
    \pgfmathparse{\zmax < \zP{\xmax}{\ymin}}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \coordinate (xmaxymin1) at ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmax}},\ymin,{\zP{\xP{\ymin}{\zmax}}{\ymin}});
        \coordinate (xmaxymin2) at ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmax}},\ymax,{\zP{\xP{\ymax}{\zmax}}{\ymax}});
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymin}{\zmax} > \xmax || \xP{\ymin}{\zmax} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xmaxymin1) at (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmax}},{\zP{\xmax}{\yP{\xmax}{\zmax}}});
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymax}{\zmax} > \xmax || \xP{\ymax}{\zmax} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xmaxymin2) at (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmax}},{\zP{\xmax}{\yP{\xmax}{\zmax}}});
        \fi
    \fi
    \pgfmathparse{\zmin > \zP{\xmax}{\ymin}}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \coordinate (xmaxymin1) at ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmin}},\ymin,{\zP{\xP{\ymin}{\zmin}}{\ymin}});
        \coordinate (xmaxymin2) at ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmin}},\ymax,{\zP{\xP{\ymax}{\zmin}}{\ymax}});
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymin}{\zmin} > \xmax || \xP{\ymin}{\zmin} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xmaxymin1) at (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmin}},{\zP{\xmax}{\yP{\xmax}{\zmin}}});
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymax}{\zmin} > \xmax || \xP{\ymax}{\zmin} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xmaxymin2) at (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmin}},{\zP{\xmax}{\yP{\xmax}{\zmin}}});
        \fi
    \fi

    \coordinate (xmaxymax1) at (\xmax,\ymax,{\zP{\xmax}{\ymax}});
    \coordinate (xmaxymax2) at (\xmax,\ymax,{\zP{\xmax}{\ymax}});
    \pgfmathparse{\zmax < \zP{\xmax}{\ymax}}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \coordinate (xmaxymax1) at ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmax}},\ymin,{\zP{\xP{\ymin}{\zmax}}{\ymin}});
        \coordinate (xmaxymax2) at ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmax}},\ymax,{\zP{\xP{\ymax}{\zmax}}{\ymax}});
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymin}{\zmax} > \xmax || \xP{\ymin}{\zmax} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xmaxymax1) at (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmax}},{\zP{\xmax}{\yP{\xmax}{\zmax}}});
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymax}{\zmax} > \xmax || \xP{\ymax}{\zmax} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xmaxymax2) at (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmax}},{\zP{\xmax}{\yP{\xmax}{\zmax}}});
        \fi
    \fi
    \pgfmathparse{\zmin > \zP{\xmax}{\ymax}}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \coordinate (xmaxymax1) at ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmin}},\ymin,{\zP{\xP{\ymin}{\zmin}}{\ymin}});
        \coordinate (xmaxymax2) at ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmin}},\ymax,{\zP{\xP{\ymax}{\zmin}}{\ymax}});
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymin}{\zmin} > \xmax || \xP{\ymin}{\zmin} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xmaxymax1) at (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmin}},{\zP{\xmax}{\yP{\xmax}{\zmin}}});
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymax}{\zmin} > \xmax || \xP{\ymax}{\zmin} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xmaxymax2) at (\xmax,{\yP{\xmax}{\zmin}},{\zP{\xmax}{\yP{\xmax}{\zmin}}});
        \fi
    \fi

    \coordinate (xminymax1) at (\xmin,\ymax,{\zP{\xmin}{\ymax}});
    \coordinate (xminymax2) at (\xmin,\ymax,{\zP{\xmin}{\ymax}});
    \pgfmathparse{\zmax < \zP{\xmin}{\ymax}}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \coordinate (xminymax1) at ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmax}},\ymin,{\zP{\xP{\ymin}{\zmax}}{\ymin}});
        \coordinate (xminymax2) at ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmax}},\ymax,{\zP{\xP{\ymax}{\zmax}}{\ymax}});
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymin}{\zmax} > \xmax || \xP{\ymin}{\zmax} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xminymax1) at (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmax}},{\zP{\xmin}{\yP{\xmin}{\zmax}}});
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymax}{\zmax} > \xmax || \xP{\ymax}{\zmax} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xminymax2) at (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmax}},{\zP{\xmin}{\yP{\xmin}{\zmax}}});
        \fi
    \fi
    \pgfmathparse{\zmin > \zP{\xmin}{\ymax}}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \coordinate (xminymax1) at ({\xP{\ymin}{\zmin}},\ymin,{\zP{\xP{\ymin}{\zmin}}{\ymin}});
        \coordinate (xminymax2) at ({\xP{\ymax}{\zmin}},\ymax,{\zP{\xP{\ymax}{\zmin}}{\ymax}});
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymin}{\zmin} > \xmax || \xP{\ymin}{\zmin} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xminymax1) at (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmin}},{\zP{\xmin}{\yP{\xmin}{\zmin}}});
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\xP{\ymax}{\zmin} > \xmax || \xP{\ymax}{\zmin} < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \coordinate (xminymax2) at (\xmin,{\yP{\xmin}{\zmin}},{\zP{\xmin}{\yP{\xmin}{\zmin}}});
        \fi
    \fi
    
    \path[spath/save=#5] 
    (xminymin2) -- (xminymin1) -- 
    (xmaxymin1) -- (xmaxymin2) -- 
    (xmaxymax1) -- (xmaxymax2) -- 
    (xminymax2) -- (xminymax1) -- 
    cycle;
\fi

}










\newcommand{\Lyofx}[1]{}
\newcommand{\Lxofy}[1]{}

\newcommand{\Lzofx}[1]{}
\newcommand{\Lxofz}[1]{}

\newcommand{\Lzofy}[1]{}
\newcommand{\Lyofz}[1]{}

\newcommand{\getLine}[9]{

\pgfmathsetmacro\aPone{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\bPone{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cPone{#3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dPone{#4}

\pgfmathsetmacro\aPtwo{#5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\bPtwo{#6}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cPtwo{#7}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dPtwo{#8}

\renewcommand{\Lyofx}[1]{((\dPtwo-(\cPtwo)*(\dPone)/(\cPone))-(\aPtwo-(\cPtwo)*(\aPone)/(\cPone))*(##1))/(\bPtwo-(\cPtwo)*(\bPone)/(\cPone))}
\renewcommand{\Lzofx}[1]{((\dPtwo-(\bPtwo)*(\dPone)/(\bPone))-(\aPtwo-(\bPtwo)*(\aPone)/(\bPone))*(##1))/(\cPtwo-(\bPtwo)*(\cPone)/(\bPone))}

\renewcommand{\Lzofy}[1]{((\dPtwo-(\aPtwo)*(\dPone)/(\aPone))-(\bPtwo-(\aPtwo)*(\bPone)/(\aPone))*(##1))/(\cPtwo-(\aPtwo)*(\cPone)/(\aPone))}
\renewcommand{\Lxofy}[1]{((\dPtwo-(\cPtwo)*(\dPone)/(\cPone))-(\bPtwo-(\cPtwo)*(\bPone)/(\cPone))*(##1))/(\aPtwo-(\cPtwo)*(\aPone)/(\cPone))}

\renewcommand{\Lyofz}[1]{((\dPtwo-(\aPtwo)*(\dPone)/(\aPone))-(\cPtwo-(\aPtwo)*(\cPone)/(\aPone))*(##1))/(\bPtwo-(\aPtwo)*(\bPone)/(\aPone))}
\renewcommand{\Lxofz}[1]{((\dPtwo-(\bPtwo)*(\dPone)/(\bPone))-(\cPtwo-(\bPtwo)*(\cPone)/(\bPone))*(##1))/(\aPtwo-(\bPtwo)*(\aPone)/(\bPone))}


% nonparallel test
\pgfmathparse{!(\aPone/\aPtwo == \bPone/\bPtwo && \aPone/\aPtwo == \cPone/\cPtwo)}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1

    \pgfmathparse{!(\bPtwo == \cPtwo*(\bPone)/(\cPone) || \cPtwo == \bPtwo*(\cPone)/(\bPone))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\xmin}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofx{\xmin}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofx{\xmin}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\xmax}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofx{\xmax}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofx{\xmax}}

        \pgfmathparse{\Lendy > \ymax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofy{\ymax}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofx{\Lxofy{\ymax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofx{\Lxofy{\ymax}}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lendy < \ymin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofy{\ymin}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofx{\Lxofy{\ymin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofx{\Lxofy{\ymin}}}
        \fi

        \pgfmathparse{\Lstarty > \ymax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofy{\ymax}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofx{\Lxofy{\ymax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofx{\Lxofy{\ymax}}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lstarty < \ymin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofy{\ymin}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofx{\Lxofy{\ymin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofx{\Lxofy{\ymin}}}
        \fi

        %%%

        \pgfmathparse{\Lendz > \zmax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofz{\zmax}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofx{\Lxofz{\zmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofx{\Lxofz{\zmax}}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lendz < \zmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofz{\zmin}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofx{\Lxofz{\zmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofx{\Lxofz{\zmin}}}
        \fi

        \pgfmathparse{\Lstartz > \zmax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofz{\zmax}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofx{\Lxofz{\zmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofx{\Lxofz{\zmax}}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lstartz < \zmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofz{\zmin}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofx{\Lxofz{\zmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofx{\Lxofz{\zmin}}}
        \fi
               
        \coordinate (Lstart) at (\Lstartx,\Lstarty,\Lstartz);
        \coordinate (Lend) at (\Lendx,\Lendy,\Lendz);
        \path[spath/save=#9] (Lstart) -- (Lend);
    \fi

    \pgfmathparse{!(\cPtwo == \aPtwo*(\cPone)/(\aPone) || \aPtwo == \cPtwo*(\aPone)/(\cPone))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofy{\ymin}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\ymin}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofy{\ymin}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofy{\ymax}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\ymax}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofy{\ymax}}

        \pgfmathparse{\Lendx > \xmax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofy{\Lyofx{\xmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofx{\xmax}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofy{\Lyofx{\xmax}}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lendx < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofy{\Lyofx{\xmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofx{\xmin}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofy{\Lyofx{\xmin}}}
        \fi

        \pgfmathparse{\Lstartx > \xmax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofy{\Lyofx{\xmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofx{\xmax}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofy{\Lyofx{\xmax}}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lstartx < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofy{\Lyofx{\xmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofx{\xmin}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofy{\Lyofx{\xmin}}}
        \fi

        %%%

        \pgfmathparse{\Lendz > \zmax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofy{\Lyofz{\zmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofz{\zmax}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofy{\Lyofz{\zmax}}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lendz < \zmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofy{\Lyofz{\zmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofz{\zmin}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofy{\Lyofz{\zmin}}}
        \fi

        \pgfmathparse{\Lstartz > \zmax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofy{\Lyofz{\zmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofz{\zmax}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofy{\Lyofz{\zmax}}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lstartz < \zmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofy{\Lyofz{\zmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofz{\zmin}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofy{\Lyofz{\zmin}}}
        \fi
               
        \coordinate (Lstart) at (\Lstartx,\Lstarty,\Lstartz);
        \coordinate (Lend) at (\Lendx,\Lendy,\Lendz);
    \fi

    \pgfmathparse{!(\bPtwo == \aPtwo*(\bPone)/(\aPone) || \aPtwo == \bPtwo*(\aPone)/(\bPone))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofz{\zmin}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofz{\zmin}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\zmin}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofz{\zmax}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofz{\zmax}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\zmax}

        \pgfmathparse{\Lendx > \xmax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofz{\Lzofx{\xmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofz{\Lzofx{\xmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofx{\xmax}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lendx < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofz{\Lzofx{\xmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofz{\Lzofx{\xmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofx{\xmin}}
        \fi

        \pgfmathparse{\Lendy > \ymax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofz{\Lzofy{\ymax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofz{\Lzofy{\ymax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofy{\ymax}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lendy < \ymin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendx{\Lxofz{\Lzofy{\ymin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendy{\Lyofz{\Lzofy{\ymin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofy{\ymin}}
        \fi

        %%%

        \pgfmathparse{\Lstartx > \xmax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofz{\Lzofx{\xmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofz{\Lzofx{\xmax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofx{\xmax}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lstartx < \xmin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofz{\Lzofx{\xmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofz{\Lzofx{\xmin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lendz{\Lzofx{\xmin}}
        \fi

        \pgfmathparse{\Lstarty > \ymax}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofz{\Lzofy{\ymax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofz{\Lzofy{\ymax}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofy{\ymax}}
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\Lstarty < \ymin}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartx{\Lxofz{\Lzofy{\ymin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstarty{\Lyofz{\Lzofy{\ymin}}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\Lstartz{\Lzofy{\ymin}}
        \fi
               
        \coordinate (Lstart) at (\Lstartx,\Lstarty,\Lstartz);
        \coordinate (Lend) at (\Lendx,\Lendy,\Lendz);

    \fi

           \path[spath/save=#9] (Lstart) -- (Lend);

\else
    % if they are parallel, do nothing
    \path[spath/save=#9];
\fi
    
}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90-\elevation}{\azimuth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    
    % floor
    \draw (\xmin,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmin);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmin);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmin);
    \draw (\xmin,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmin,\ymin,\zmin);
    % spokes
    \draw (\xmin,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmin,\ymin,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmin,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmax);
    % roof
    \draw (\xmin,\ymin,\zmax) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymin,\zmax) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymax,\zmax) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmin,\ymax,\zmax) -- (\xmin,\ymin,\zmax);

    \pgfmathsetmacro\aPone{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bPone{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cPone{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dPone{4}
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro\aPtwo{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bPtwo{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cPtwo{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dPtwo{0}
    
    \getPlane{\aPone}{\bPone}{\cPone}{\dPone}{Pone}
    \getPlane{\aPtwo}{\bPtwo}{\cPtwo}{\dPtwo}{Ptwo}
    \getLine{\aPone}{\bPone}{\cPone}{\dPone}{\aPtwo}{\bPtwo}{\cPtwo}{\dPtwo}{Lint}
    
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[spath/use=Pone];
        \scoped[
            spath/split at intersections={Pone}{Lint},
            spath/remove components={Pone}{1},
            ]
        \fill[red, fill=green]
            (spath cs:{Pone} 1) [spath/use={Pone}]
                                [spath/use={Lint, reverse}]
            -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[spath/use=Ptwo];
        \draw[blue, fill=orange, spath/use=Ptwo];
    \end{scope}
    \scoped[
        spath/split at intersections={Pone}{Lint},
        spath/remove components={Pone}{0},
        ]
    \fill[red, fill=green]
        (spath cs:{Pone} 0) [spath/use={Pone}]
                            [spath/use={Lint, reverse}]
        -- cycle;
    \draw[thick, spath/use=Lint];

        

    % spokes
    %\draw (\xmin,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmin,\ymin,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmin,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymax,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymin,\zmin) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmax);
    % roof
    \draw (\xmin,\ymin,\zmax) -- (\xmax,\ymin,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymin,\zmax) -- (\xmax,\ymax,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmax,\ymax,\zmax) -- (\xmin,\ymax,\zmax);
    \draw (\xmin,\ymax,\zmax) -- (\xmin,\ymin,\zmax);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I don't want to add axes because it would be really tedious to calculate their intersections with the planes. Instead, my recommendation is to mark the edges of the "box", like in pgfplots

Note: I improved on this solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731036/319072
